# Retrieve spreadsheet value-being-entered via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhwyMSCxcpA3B-Kixpdrb8W4lFgpktOrEKHef6DF5X8/edit?usp=sharing

I'm creating a function in a sheet that I have made and cannot figure out how to return the current cell input that a user has entered in the formula bar, but has failed to press enter on the keyboard before clicking a save button image that executes a 'saveNewEntry' function.

Action Causing Function Issue:

Click on cell F4 and type in 100, do not press enter or click another cell and just immediately click the save button that is linked to the function.  You will see that the user input '100' since enter was not pressed and a different cell was not clicked remains in the formula bar and does not save below the 'Saved Entries Last 500' line.

I hope that made sense.  Any help on how to make this happen would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's saving the current value as expected. The current cell value never changes unless Enter or the cell is clicked off onto another cell. Clicking an image ( the Save button ) is not clicking another cell because it's actually on top of all the cells ( even though it appears embedded inside one ).

I'd recommend throwing the entry submission inside the sidebar as an Add-on. The current value of a text box there could always be grabbed when Save or Submit is pressed, unlike in cells.